# How to edit navbar from another page using Layout?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I've a navbar in my _Layout.cshtml, it includes home, register, login. When the user is registered and only at this time I want navbar to contain also a new element as a little image, which will redirect to some page. How can I add smth to my navbar from the page which's using this _Layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

You can put a flag in your navbar in _Layout.cshtml page.

1. Get data from the database to know if your use is registered or not? If yes then set the flag to TRUE in your **ViewBag**.

Code in your controller:

```
ViewBag.IsRegistered= true;
```

2. And pass this model in your cshtml page

Here is the sample:

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">  
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">  
            <li>  
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">  
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>  
                      Home  
                </a>  
            </li>  
            <li>  
                <a href="@Url.Action("Register", "Register")">  
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>  
                    Register
                </a>  
            </li>  
            <li>  
            <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Login")">  
                Login
            </a>  
            </li> 
            @{ 
            if(@ViewBag.IsRegistered){
            <li>  
            <a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Home")">  
                <img src="path to image" alt="test"> 
            </a>  
            </li> 
              }    
            }
        </ul>  
    </div>
```